# Best, free and multiplatform screen annotation software

Tags: display, annotation, whiteboard

I am looking for multiplatform desktop screen annotation software (not communicator or screen recorder).

I am conducting lectures on multiple platforms, like Windows or macOS.
Recently, I was performing the classes using text editors, paint/gimp, etc.

But sometimes, I find it hard to explain some things this way. It would be nice to have some tool that allows me to draw on the screen and use it on all platforms like Windows or macOS.

I researched and found some tools available online.

- EpicPen - It is the first result Google returns. It is available only for windows and macOS, and the functionality is quite limited (for example, drawing lines or squares is unavailable, there are only 16 colours, and whiteboard/blackboard are not available). EpicPen pro, on the other hand, is available only for windows (https://epic-pen.com/).
- Windows Snipping Tool - This one, as most of you know, is a windows tool and is quite constrained and available only for windows (obviously).
- ppInk - another annotation software for Windows, this one looks interesting, but it sometimes hangs on my machine, nevertheless it is only for Windows (https://github.com/pubpub-zz/ppInk).
- gInk - similar to above, again only Windows (https://github.com/geovens/gInk)
- live-draw - Only windows, requires .net (https://github.com/antfu/live-draw)
- OpenBoard - only whiteboard tool but cross-platform (Windows, Linux, macOS) (https://openboard.ch/index.en.html)
- SnagIt - it's more screen shoot maker, quite expensive, and only for windows and mac (https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html)
- UltimatePen - commercial, only free trial, only for macOS (http://www.snowmintcs.com/products/ultimatepenmac/)
- TuxPen - author claims that is it not completed and some functionality looks not working (https://github.com/csgn/TuxPen)
- ScreenPen - multiplatform, requires Python, installation with pip, supports charts using matplotlib, but it's mentioned that the support could be improved (https://github.com/rsusik/screenpen)
- Draw Over - only windows and Linux (mac is not listed) (https://gilzoide.itch.io/draw-over)
- ShareX - only windows, also file sharing tool (https://getsharex.com/)

To summarize, I created the below table:

| Name | Free | Windows | Linux | MacOS | Shapes | White/blackboard |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [EpicPen](https://epic-pen.com/) | Partially | Yes | No | Yes (only basic) | Yes | Paid |
| Windows Snipping Tool | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No |
| [ppInk](https://github.com/pubpub-zz/ppInk) | Yes | Yes | No | No | Yes | No |
| [gInk](https://github.com/geovens/gInk) | Yes | Yes | No | No | Yes | No |
| [LiveDraw](https://github.com/antfu/live-draw) | Yes | Yes | No | No | Yes | No |
| **[OpenBoard](https://openboard.ch/index.en.html)** | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Only |
| [SnagIt](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) | No | Yes | No? | No? | Yes | No? |
| [UltimatePen](http://www.snowmintcs.com/products/ultimatepenmac) | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | No |
| **[TuxPen](https://github.com/csgn/TuxPen)** | Yes | Yes? | Yes | Yes? | No? | No? |
| **[ScreenPen](https://github.com/rsusik/screenpen)** | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| **[Draw Over](https://gilzoide.itch.io/draw-over)** | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | Yes | No? |
| [Sharex](https://getsharex.com/) | Yes | Yes | No | No | Yes | No? |

I marked bold those that look promising in my personal opinion (multiplatform and free is the priority). OpenBoard is the only whiteboard tool. In some cases, it has limited functionality (and maybe shouldn't be enumerated here).

Tuxpen is incomplete, and even the author writes in README that there are functions not working. The ScreenPen looks very interesting, the matplotlib support sound very good, but seems it is not a mature software and requires Python. Similar case with Draw Over. It appears to be an experimental software (written in-game engine), plus it has limited functionality (no whiteboard and macOS support).

I would like to know your recommendation, especially those who have already used any of these tools or maybe there is someone who tested them already and decided which one to use.

*Disclaimer: I prepared this table only for my cases. There are some functionalities that I didn't enumerate here and maybe good for somebody else. Please let me know if I missed any software that is worth adding to this list. I used google and GitHub for searching the software*

Comment: On Windows only (that's why only a comment and not an answer) - [ShareX](https://alternativeto.net/software/sharex/about/) is my go to tool.
Why is it important for it to be multi-platform, if for each platform you'll get the 'best of class' there?

Comment: @Lockszmith Thank you for sharing it. I will add it to the list. Are you using this tool on a daily basis? Regarding "multiplatform", it's only because I don't want to learn a separate tool for each platform. It's nice to work intuitively without bothering with questions such as "where is that option in this tool?".

Comment: Yes, I use ShareX daily. I disable the automatic upload, and enable multi-region capture. This allows me to hit prtscr, and then select multiple regions as well as have the editor visible. --- Microsoft has a very good web-based (which also has an application in Windows) whiteboard which is free and allows multi-user realtime collaboration, so combining these 2 tools can probably give you a very powerful combination. --- While I hear you about wanting everything to be the same, there is a reason you use Linux and not Windows all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found this link on Google -
[Click here](https://windowsreport.com/screen-annotation-software/)

It lists the best screen annotation software. There are 10+ good screen annotation software on this site.

Zoom is actually an application for online classes or lectures. It has good screen annotation tools. But you have to use Zoom for your lectures to use the tools. Share the screen with your students and use the screen annotation tools!

[image: Screen annotation tools of Zoom]

Comment: Right, Zoom is multiplatform but it is a communicator and not a screen annotation app. I use already a different communicator and not going to change it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not cross platform compatible but [ZoomIt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/zoomit) is a neat little free programm for zooming and screen annotations for Windows. It also supports some basic shapes.

Comment: Just FYI, as you mentioned, it's not cross-platform (which is one of the OP's primary requirements).  Potential users should be aware that the developer is a VP at Microsoft, where the mantra is to push people to "upgrade" to the latest version of Windows.  The developer has stated that he is not willing to have his software support multiple releases of Windows.  So don't get too attached to his utilities unless you like to keep on having to buy new hardware to support Microsoft's "upgrades".